# Client Exception: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I've been playing around with my Java client app. Behaviour is very similar to this post (and others):

[java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed)

As yet I've not found the answer - hence this post. I have a idea what is wrong but I'm not sure what to do about it.

The protocol is simple - read some data in, send back an ACK and repeat (until terminted).

I've been looking at what is going on with WireShark, and is seems the TCP window is filling up. I'm performing a flush() on the DataOutputStream (For the ACKs) but doesn't change the fact at after a while I get this exception (I can see on WireShark that there is always a window problem right before the Java exception).

So how to I make sure in Java that my TCP windows/buffers are clear (Which I think is the root cause of the problem?) seems to be no flush on the DataInputStream. Make be wonder that whilst I might be reading it the TCP stack is filling up.

Many Thanks

Mark

I've attached the basic code calls below:

```
     public void connectToServer()
 {
     //Create socket connection      
     try
     {
         if (lSocket == null)
         {
             lSocket = new Socket("localhost", 7651);
             lSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
             lInDataStream = new DataInputStream(lSocket.getInputStream());
             lOutDataStream = new DataOutputStream(lSocket.getOutputStream());
         }
     }
     catch (UnknownHostException e)
     {
         System.out.println("Unknown host: localhost");
     }
     catch  (IOException e)
     {
         System.out.println("No I/O");
     }       
 }

 public void readSocket() throws IOException
 {
     //Receive data from ROS SerialtoNetwork server
     if (lSocket != null)
     {
        lInDataStream.readInt();    
        lInDataStream.readFully(cbuf);

        lOutDataStream.writeBytes("Ack");
        lOutDataStream.flush();

        //String lstr = new String(cbuf);
        //System.out.print(lstr);
        //System.out.println(""); 
    }
 }

 public String getDataBuffer()
 {
     String lstr = new String(cbuf);
     return lstr;
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the capture file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed)

Answer (score 0):

This indicates persistent network errors. There are several (repetitive) MSDN article on this error, e.g. [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832256.aspx).