# JSP and Servlet socketinput Exception

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Can anyone take me out of this problem?

```
NotifyUtil::java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2959)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.NotifyUtil$RecordSender.run(NotifyUtil.java:299)
```

Comment: Tell us more about the scenario where you are facing this problem.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed

Answer (score 0):

This means there is some network error. The network error could be due to the following reasons:

- timeout , the server has not responded before idle timeout
- network disturbance

Comment: yes it must be due to network disturbance. Thank you very much

Comment: sir i am facing a problem in jsp and servlet with designing issues, my problem is that my design changes when i reload the page. I guess it must be a problem with the path of css, but i could not solve the problem. can you pleas help me?