# Client Server sockets java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed)

I'm trying to write a client server pair where the connection is live all day and the client waits for the server to send a message.  The steps are:

1. Server opens port and listens for connection
2. Client connects in and waits for data
3. Some time later (maybe hours) the server sends data to the client
4. Client processes data and returns it to the server
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4

I can get steps 1-4 working, however if I try to repeat step 3 I get the error in the title.

This is my method on the client side:

```
private static void waitForInput(SSLSocket sslsocket) throws IOException {
        do {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());

                Object o = (Object) (ois.readObject());
                // excluded code to process data     

                oos.flush();
                oos.writeObject(o);
                oos.reset();
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } while ( true );
    }
```

The code fails on the 4th line, The first time around it blocks and waits until I get the next bit of data, but it doesn't work twice.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the "4th line"? And in what way does it fail? All you say is that it "doesn't work".

Comment: Literally the 4th line in the code I have above `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());`

The error I get is the one in the title - 'java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection abort IOException is thrown when you are waiting to read from a socket that has been closed at the other end, check to see your server side code , if you are not accidentally closing the socket. 
Also the server side code could be uploaded for deeper analysis, also try posting the stack trace, it will help analyzing.

Comment: Ah you were right, I was resetting the connection on the other end, I need to just leave it active for the day.

Comment: @Sarah No it isn't. It is caused by the local network stack in response to transmission errors. If the peer closes the connection you get an EOS from the API: in this case, an EOFException. Completely incorrect answer. -1.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the declaration for `ois` and `oos` out of the `do ... while` loop, since there is no need to redeclare them everytime, might need a `try ... catch` around that.

```
private static void waitForInput(SSLSocket sslsocket) throws IOException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());
    do {
        try {

            Object o = (Object) (ois.readObject());
            // excluded code to process data     

            oos.writeObject(o);
            oos.flush();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } while ( true );
}
```

And I have removed the `oos.reset();` and moved the `oos.flush();`

I believe that the problem is the `oos.reset();` and i would never reset a connection that is supposed to be persistent for hours, or, at least part of it.

Besides there is already a `ois` for that connection and you don't need two of them.

Comment: Thank you, yes I ended up moving those calls out of the do loop just as you mentioned.