# Apache Camel fails after proxy when hitting the endPoint. SocketException

Tags: apache, proxy, apache-camel

Can someone provide your thoughts. what is going wrong on my configuration.

This was one approach:

```
public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {
    final SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext();
    camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost","webproxy.lon.corp.services");
    camelContext.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort","80");
    camelContext.addRoutes(new CortellisRouteBuilder(env));
    return camelContext;
}
```

Second Approach

```
https4://xxxxxx/xxxx/ws/rs/xx-v1/match?authUsername=someUsernamexxx&authPassword=xxxxxxxxx&authMethod=Digest&proxyHost=webproxy.services.xxx.com&proxyPort=80&proxyAuthScheme=http4
```

both does not work. below is the exception that i receive. it does 3 retires and then fails.

```
Exchange[
Id                  ID-UC193537-TPL-A-54917-1428598980021-0-2
ExchangePattern     InOut
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-UC193537-TPL-A-54917-1428598980021-0-1,   
CamelAcceptContentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded,   

CamelHttpMethod=POST,camelHttpQuery=text=Paracetamol,   
camelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
BodyType            null
Body                [Body is null]]
```

====================================================================

```
    I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request:  
    Software caused connection abort: recv failed
   2015-04-09 18:04:36,876 - INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-  
   4:HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry@445] - Retrying request
   2015-04-09 18:04:37,015 - INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-  
   4:HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry@439] - I/O exception   
  (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused 
  connection abort: recv failed
  2015-04-09 18:04:37,015 - INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec-  
  4:HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry@445] - Retrying request
  2015-04-09 18:04:37,167 - INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec- 
  4:HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry@439] - I/O exception  
  (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused  
  connection abort: recv failed
  2015-04-09 18:04:37,168 - INFO  [http-apr-8080-exec- 
  4:HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry@445] - Retrying request
  2015-04-09 18:04:37,298 - ERROR [http-apr-8080-exec-
  4:MarkerIgnoringBase.error@161] - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID- 
  UC193537-TPL-A-54917-1428598980021-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-UC193537-TPL-A- 
  54917-1428598980021-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: 
  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

====================================================================

```
   java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:173)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
            at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
            at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
            at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
          at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
         at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
         at
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when the local network system aborts a connection, see e.g. [java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed).

The proxy server may abort the connection. Can you try to connect to your service directly (= not through your proxy)?

Comment: Hi Peter, directly i am able to hit the URL, but all the traffic needs to be route via proxy on the test and production environments.hence the need for proxy.

Comment: @user3022698 Perhaps you need to set `http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword` too.

Comment: Hi Peter,within the firewall, we were told that we dont have to use the username and password.similar code with apache client works fine.private Client createProxyClient(String proxyUri) {
  final DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig config = new DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig();
  config.getProperties().put(DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig.PROPERTY_PROXY_URI, proxyUri); // http://xxxxxxProxyhost:80
  return ApacheHttpClient.create(config);
    }

Comment: Hi Peter,i found a peculiar problem. i tried with 2 scenarios,1) Open API like weather, where you dont have authentication ,it works fine with proxy 2) API with authentication included as part of the URL outputs "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed". both go via webproxy, which does not require authentication

Comment: [Loaded sun.net.NetProperties$1 from /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector$2 from /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.Proxy from /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.net.Proxy$Type from /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]
^C[Loaded sun.misc.Signal$1 from /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar]

Answer (score 0):

```
cortellis.ontologiesNerUrl=https4://xxxx/ls-api-ws/ws/rs/xxxx-v1/ner?proxyPort=80&proxyHost=xxxxxxxx&authMethod=Basic&authUsername=TR_Internal_024&authPassword=ZTYA5S1KLF7WCDMN&**proxyAuthScheme=http4**
```

with addition of proxyAuthScheme=http4 **it worked for rest based URL, But not for SOAP based URL**

```
i have picked the latest camel version 2.15.1
```

Comment: @peter it worked for both REST and SOAP on windows. **but does not work on linux.gives me a timeout error.**