# Jenkins slaves are disconnecting from master with java.net.SocketException

Tags: jenkins, jnlp, jenkins-agent

Starting today some of our slaves in our Jenkins master started to disconnect with the following error:

```
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
May 31, 2016 3:27:07 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.EngineUtil.readLine(EngineUtil.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpProtocol2.performHandshake(JnlpProtocol2.java:74)
```

I've read about this issue and tried to figure out what caused it. I have around 85% or the rest of my windows slaves still connected and running.

- Slaves : Windows server 2012R2
- Connected with JNLP protocol
- Jenkins version : 1.609.3

If more information is needed let me know and I'll supply it.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that there was a network error, such as a TCP timeout. I would start by placing a sniffer (wireshark) on the connection to see if you can see any problems. If there is a TCP error, you should be able to see it. Also, you can check your router logs, if this is applicable. If wireless is involved anywhere, that is another source for these kind of errors.

Duplicate: [java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed)