# Software caused connection abort: recv failed when calling REST WebService in SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I've made a SpringBoot back-end and exposed some REST services.
I want to make a call of an external REST Webservice in this back-end on a webservice call.

Here's the code of the external call :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36");
HttpEntity<MonObjet> entity = new HttpEntity<MonObjet>(headers);
ResponseEntity<MonObjet> result = restTemplate.exchange("urlDuService", HttpMethod.GET, entity, MonObjet.class);
```

When i'm calling this code from a main(), it's working fine.
Bhen when i deploy it with spring-boot (in tomcat so...), and call it from my own webService, i've got a

> "SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed".

Any advices about it ? I've seen many posts about this error and try many ways, but i'm still stuck.

Thanks in advance

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135919/java-net-socketexception-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already seens theses links. But i've read them again and... i don't know why, but it's working now without changing anything. I've just restarted my server (and my computer). So it was indirectly the solution :)